# DocumentsContract.copyDocument() always fails

Tags: android, document

```
final String AUTHORITY = "com.android.externalstorage.documents";

Uri roottree  = DocumentsContract.buildTreeDocumentUri(AUTHORITY,"primary:");
Uri sourceuri = DocumentsContract.buildDocumentUriUsingTree(roottree,DocumentsContract.geTreeDocumentId(roottree) + "Folder1");
Uri TargetUri = DocumentsContract.buildDocumentUriUsingTree(roottree,DocumentsContract.getTreeDocumentId(roottree) + "Folder2");
Uri resulturi = DocumentsContract.copyDocument(myContentResolver,sourceuri,TargetUri);
```

Copying Folder1 into Folder2 always return null. CreateDocument, DeleteDocument even MoveDocument working without any issue.

Comment: You are very unlikely to have rights to work with `Uri` values created by harcoded authorities and names.

Comment: sir, can you explain a little more?

Comment: You have to have permission to read and write documents and trees. Your app will only get that permission using the Storage Access Framework, such as `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE`. And, if you use those, you get `Uri` values to use, rather than needing to hard-code stuff as you are doing here.

Comment: sir, I have permission using the below code:                                                        
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE);
                        intent.putExtra(DocumentsContract.EXTRA_INITIAL_URI, docUri);
                        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
                        startActivityForResult(intent, 1);                                                          and Create, Delete and Move operations are working successfully.

Comment: I have a similar problem with DocumentsContract.copyDocument.
Each time my program crashes: "java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Copy not supported"
The curios thing is below listed actions are working fine!!
DocumentsContract.moveDocument
DocumentsContract.deleteDocument
DocumentsContract.renameDocument
How come document moving, deleting and renaming is supported but not the copying of one?
Can anyone help me in this issue? Any hint will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it was a deliberately bug.
It didn't work and you need to rebuild the function.
Here is simple sample:

```
public boolean copyFileUri(Uri FilePath, Uri ToFolder, String Name){boolean done=true;
    try {
        InputStream in = this.getContentResolver().openInputStream(FilePath);
        Uri uriOut=DocumentsContract.createDocument(getContentResolver(), ToFolder,  "text/plain", Name );
        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(uriOut, "w").getFileDescriptor());
        Uri uRename=DocumentsContract.renameDocument(getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(), uriOut, Name );
        if (uRename==null){/*RENAME WITH WHILE COUNTER*/}
        try { byte[] buf = new byte[1024]; int len; while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) { out.write(buf, 0, len); } } catch(Exception e){done=false;}
        out.close(); in.close();
    } catch(Exception e){done=false;} return done;      
}
```

Note that you will need to DIY additional function for these case:

- The destination folder have files with the same name, you need to add counter for rename or a switch to overwrite old file.
- If you want to copy folder, it will a little more complex by add:

  - Detect Uri was folder or normal file
  - Create folder
  - Scan File
  - Recursion calling itself when scan so it scan whole the tree.